# How is eye color in humans inherited?

Tags: genetics, human-anatomy, human-genetics

In high school we studied the inheritance of eye color, as it was explained to us in the most simple way: blue eye color is a recessive, monogenic, autosomal trait. Now I know that it is a bit more complicated than that; there are several genes which determine the inheritance of eye color. That's as far as I my knowledge goes.

Which are these genes and what do they encode for? How is the eye color trait inherited? Provided that a man with blue eyes and a woman with brown eyes have a child, can the probability of their child to have blue eyes be calculated?

Answer (score 8):

It is mainly determined by the OCA2 gene, but it also likely involves several other genes, including TYR, TYRP1, HERC2, and several others. To complicate things further, it is not a "mutant/wild type" trait, but multiple normal alleles can be found in the population, and it is believed that the sum of these single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs) determine the final phenotype.

I took the info from a [2004 review by Sturm and Frudakis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952504001593) and a more recent paper from [Liu et al, 2009](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982209005971)

Comment: This answer is so close to be good... why don't you expand a little on what those genes do and how they influence color? I know you linked the papers but it would be much nicer if the answer were self-sufficient. For instance you could say that OCA2 encodes for the P protein, a (supposed) Tyr transporter that allows Tyr, a precursor of the brown pigment melanin, to get into the cells.

Comment: @aleadam Thanks for your answer, it really looks promising, but I was about to ask you the same thing as nico did: can you please expand it and make it more clear and easy to read and understand?

Comment: omim might also be helpful: http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?omim+227220

Answer (score 5):

There is [a nice page](http://www.athro.com/evo/gen/genefr2.html) that tries to explain this:

> The known Human Eye color genes are: EYCL1 (also called gey), the Green/blue eye color gene, 
>   located on chromosome 19 (though there is
>   also evidence that another gene with similar activity exists but is
>   not on chromosome 19). EYCL2 (also called bey1), the central brown eye
>   color gene, possibly located on chromosome 15. EYCL3 (also called
>   bey2), the Brown/blue eye color gene located on chromosome 15. EYCL3
>   probably involves mutations in the regulatory region just before the
>   OCA2 gene (which produces a protein that is expressed in melanocytes).
>   A second gene for green has also been postulated. Other eye colors
>   including grey and hazel are not yet explained. We do not yet know
>   what these genes make, or how they produce eye colors. The two gene
>   model (EYCL1 and EYCL3) used above explains only a portion of human
>   eye color inheritance. Both additional eye color genes and modifier
>   genes are almost certainly involved.

There is even [an interactive calculator](http://www.athro.com/evo/gen/genefr2.html) available.