# Eye color genetics

Tags: genetics, eyes, mathematical-models

I am trying to find a model to link the phenotype eye color to its genotypes.

I know that there exists a simple model from Davenport, which explains *{brown,blue}* eyes. Further, there is an extended model for *{brown,green,blue,gray}* eyes, based on the two genes *bey2* and *gey*. There are plenty of articles suggesting further genes which may or may not have certain impacts.

Is there a model which is more precise than the above mentioned, but which is well applicable (i.e. does not introduce excessive complexity and has greater accuracy)? I am trying to come up with some probabilistic calculations, and could well handle one or two further genes. It would also be interesting to know about the accuracy of the model.

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/728/how-is-eye-color-in-humans-inherited answer your question?

Comment: Not really.. I had seen the question and also read the mentioned papers. However, what I am looking for is a still simple model, which goes into some more depth than the two gene model (also mentioned in linked questions comments: http://www.athro.com/evo/gen/genefr2.html)